# Disable text selection popup on Bigquery UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Every time I'm composing queries in the BQ UI, if my mouse hovers over a column name after I've typed it in the query editor box it brings up the column name and type in a little window.

Does anyone know how to stop this happening as it's super annoying when trying to edit queries with the stupid popup constantly coming up??

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCYQG.png):
[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot to see exactly which popup you are referring too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [BigQuery UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) within the Google Cloud Platform Console as the query editor doesn't have the column information pop up. Keep in mind that as it's a [beta release](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#top_of_page) the popup may be present in future releases and consider its [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#limitations).

I suggest opening a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) about having an option to enable or disable this pop up within the Google Issue Tracker for both BigQuery UIs.